# format and resend form data from PHP script as if it came from an HTML form

Tags: php, forms

Is there a way that I can have a form that submits (via POST) a form element to a PHP script on my server... then have the PHP script re-encode the data and send to another server, as if it came from an HTML form?

I basically need to intercept one of my forms that users will use, so that I can record data (which are lists, nothing confidential or personal information) that the user selects in the first form, then it will be processed by my PHP script, but then I want it to be re-encoded as if it was coming directly from the original HTML form (as I have to submit some hidden fields to the final destination server after my PHP script works with the POSTed form data.

How can this be done?  and if someone could give a simple example, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks

Comment: Use cURL to post data to the second form.